# Magento 2 : get csv file download in frontend based on click of button

Tags: magento2, csv

How can i download csv file in magento 2 using below code is from controller,

```
public function execute(){
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $heading = array('Name','Sku','Qty','Price','Manufacturer');    
    $outputFile = "products_". date('Ymd_His').".csv";
    $handle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
    fputcsv($handle, $heading);

               $this->downloadCsv($outputFile);
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*');
                return $resultRedirect;
}
public function downloadCsv($file){
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            //set appropriate headers
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();flush();
            readfile($file);
        } 
    }
```

Csv file not downloaded using above code. Data are getting right for me.
Thanks.

Comment: see if this helps http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96971/magento2-file-download-action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code. You just need to remove below code:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*');
return $resultRedirect;
```

You have no need to redirect any page while downloading any CSV file.

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks its working fine after remove/comment redirect url